# How can I stop people posting on my homepage on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

I can't seem to find any way to stop people posting on my homepage on Facebook.
Is there a way?

Answer (score 4):

By "homepage" I guess you mean timeline.

If that is the case then you need to:

- Log in to Facebook
- Select the drop down menu from the arrow and select `Privacy Settings` (Fig. 1)
- Click the `Custom` cog wheel (Fig. 2)
- In the section called `Timeline and Tagging` click `edit settings`
- In the popup click the drop down next to `Who can post on your timeline?` and select `No one` (Fig. 3)
- Click `Done`

**Fig. 1**

[image: Step One]

**Fig. 2**

[image: Step Two]

**Fig. 3**

[image: Step Three]

Comment: You can also control posting with the setting under this, "Who can see what others post on your timeline?" -- if they can't see what others post then they are not able to post either.  That is useful if you want to restrict posting to a subset of friends, which you can't do with just the first setting.